# How do I undo a deleted trunk that someone else has checked in?

Tags: linux, svn

My project directory inside trunk has been accidentally deleted by another user.

I can see my project when browsing it through the web at one revision (364), but the top of the tree it is missing (370)

How do I undo those commits and get my source tree back using the command line subversion client?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the hints.  It was a combination of answers that helped me solve it.  Although Avi's answer is the closest to the one that allowed me to restore the source tree.  So I'll accept that.  Although to be totally correct, below is what worked for me since even the trunk directory was eventually removed!

Final solution was:

```
svn cp https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url/trunk@364 https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url
```

I then checked this out locally:

```
svn co https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url/trunk
```

Copied my changes into this.  Double check it builds without issues.
Followed by:

```
svn up
svn commit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy it back to the current revision:

```
svn cp -r<revision where it existed> <project-url> <project-url>
```

**EDIT:**

Note that if you have changes to your working copy, you need to take care that they don't get overwritten when updating the working copy.

In this case, I suggest you copy them somewhere safe, then doing the `svn cp` I suggested above, and doing `svn up` to update your copy, before copying your local changes back in and committing.

Comment: Ok, now the whole trunk directory has been removed.  and if I try svn cp -r364 https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url/trunk https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url/trunk it says "... path not found"

Comment: Do I omit trunk on the last url or do I need to create trunk first in the head revision?

Comment: Ok, what you have is almost right.  The correct command is svn cp https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url/trunk@364 https://xxx.xxx.xxx/url

Comment: Now, getting my changes into it.  I think the safest will be to check out the head revision, copy in my changes and check that back in.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn up -r[revision]
```

Find the revision number first by doing `svn log`

Comment: Will that not end up deleting my working copy as it'll update to a deleted revision?

Comment: I wasn't aware you had changes to local working copy. I believe this would delete those changes.